Using Elsa Workflow 3.0 with ABP Framework and use sqlserver
I want to update to Elsa workflow version 3.1.3 but i can't find any document intruct how to use elsa  worlkflow 3 with abp framework and using sqlserver
i follow like document elsa but it is for sqllite
Please help me  . Thanks !

https://community.abp.io/posts/using-elsa-workflow-with-the-abp-framework-773siqi9
This article may be useful to you.
